# Laravel and redis in docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, redis, containers

I am new to both redis and Docker so I'm a bit confused about how to go abouts setting up the environment. I have set up a Redis container and a Laravel container but don't understand how to connect them. I have entered the correct information into the .env file in Laravel but I receive this error message:

Please make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled.

Do I need to install something in the Laravel container in order to connect properly to the Redis container? Won't installing redis in the Laravel container go against the concept of containers? It is probably a silly question but I can barely find any useful information online.

Comment: you can use this https://laradock.io/

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a go.